# Launch PowerShell as administrator in current directory

Tags: powershell, shortcut

New to PowerShell.
I need to launch PowerShell as **Administrator** in the **current directory**.

From what I have heard about the amazing abilities of PowerShell, I expect I should be able to do this without a registry hack?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1309679/open-powershell-as-administrator-at-current-file-explorer-directory-keyboard-sho

this answer your question?

Comment: From PowerShell, or from Explorer?

Comment: I wanted to do this in FileExplorer.  Thanks Danilo for your link to superuser.com.   **"press [Alt] [F] [S] [A] one key right after the other"** works.

Comment: Note: This shortcut does not work if you have a Profile which specifies a directory via Set-Location!